# For loop in python and use elements of list as variables for MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, for-loop, python-2.7, tuples

two questions:
So I have a list of filenames, each of which I would like to feed into a MYSQL query.
The first questions is how to loop through the filelist and pass the elements (the filenames) as a variable to MYSQL?
The second question is: How do I print the results in a more elegant way without the parenthesis and L's form the Tuple output that is returned? THe way I have below works for three columns, but I'd like a flexible way that I don't have to add sublists (cleaned1, 2..) when I fetch more rows.
Any help highly appreciated!!!

```
MyConnection = MySQLdb.connect( host = "localhost", user = "root", \
                            passwd = "xxxx", db = "xxxx")
MyCursor = MyConnection.cursor()

**MyList= (File1, File2, File3, File...., File36)
For i in Mylist:
   do MYSQL query**

SQL = """SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column2 FROM **i in MyList** a, table2 b WHERE         
a.column1=b.column1;"""
SQLLen = MyCursor.execute(SQL)  # returns the number of records retrieved

AllOut = MyCursor.fetchall()   
**List = list(AllOut) # this puts all the TUple information into a list
cleaned = [i[0] for i in List] # this cleans up the Tuple characters)
cleaned1 = [i[1] for i in List] # this cleans up the Tuple characters)
cleaned2 = [i[2] for i in List] # this cleans up the Tuple characters)
NewList=zip(cleaned,cleaned1,cleaned2) # This makes a new List 
print NewList[0:10]**

# Close the files
MyCursor.close()
MyConnection.close()
```

I can figure out the saving to file, but I don't know how to pass a python variable into MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

convert the tuple to a list first: using

```
MyList = list(MyList)
```

and you will have two options:
try this:

```
for tablename in MyList:

    c.execute("SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column2 FROM %s a, table2 b WHERE          a.column1=b.column1", (tablename))
```

or :

```
for tablename in MyList:

    SQL= "SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column2 FROM tablevar a, table2 b WHERE          a.column1=b.column1"
    SQL = SQL.replace('tablevar', tablename)
    c.execute(SQL)
```

to print the results without the brackets you can use :

```
for tablename in MyList:
    print tablename
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply: I haven't tried the loop yet, bu the list does not work for me, that is why I have this complex sublist (cleaned1, cleaned2...) If I try to print "List" in my orignial script, I get the values but all in brackets and L's...I don't know why it does not work- everything I found in the internet (as well as your answer) suggests it should work. Thanks

Comment: did you try to print it this way? 
`for tablename in MyList: print tablename` this will print it without brackets. I updated my answer